# Using Python's re.sub to change all instances of escaped three digits to an UTF-8 character

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
string = r"string\032with\032backslash\032\092\032and\010new\035line"
```

What I want to do is change all escaped triples of digits (which are meant to be read decimally) into their utf-8 form using `chr()`.

What I tried to do was

```
re.sub('(\\[0-9]{3})', chr('\1'), string)
```

as re.sub allows users to use matched groups in replacement. But this does not work. What would be the correct way to do this?

EDIT:

```
string="string"+chr(32)+'with'+chr(32)+'backslash'+chr(32)+chr(92)+chr(32)+'and'+chr(10)+'new'+chr(35)+'line'
```

returns (correctly)

```
string with backslash\ and
new#line
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "their utf-8 form" (or at least, it doesn't make sense to say such a thing in this context), and the string that you show does not contain any backslash symbols - there is nothing to unescape. Just use `string` as it already is.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The backslash (\092), however, does not show, when I print the string. The rest does.

Comment: "\092" is seen as "\0" followed by a literal 92.

Comment: First off, `\092` **does not** encode a backslash. Three-digit encodings use base eight, not base ten - the `9` and `2` will not even be part of the escape sequence. Second, the point is that your string *does not actually have* any backslashes in it. When you `print` the string, you will not see, for example, a backslash, a digit zero, a digit three and a digit two - because the string doesn't contain those things. You will see an end-of-file character (Unicode code point 26) - or perhaps not, because it is not supposed to be a printable character (my terminal shows a replacement glyph).

Comment: Use `for c in "string\032with\032backslash\032\092\032and\010new\035line": print(c, ord(c))` to see the real characters and their unicode code points in your string.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I understand what you said; the problem is that it is my task to parse the string and turn all occurences of `\three_digits` where the three digits represent the *decimal* representation of the unicode character. The goal is to use chr() on the three digits as it actually returns the correct value, as can be seen in the edit of my question.

Comment: So, what you are working with isn't `"string\032with\032backslash\032\092\032and\010new\035line"` but `r"string\032with\032backslash\032\092\032and\010new\035line"`?

Comment: @Sören Yes, that is correct, i should have clarified that in the question

Comment: See also the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.sub) for `re.sub`. Especially note how `repl` is described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made 2 mistakes:

1. Your pattern needs to be a raw string as well (otherwise the `\\` will be a string containing a single `\`, which as magic properties inside a regex.)
2. If you want to make any changes to the replacement (here: remove the `\` and convert the number into an integer and then into a character) you need to use a function.

```py
>>> re.sub(r'(\\[0-9]{3})', lambda match: chr(int(match.group(0)[1:])), string)
'string with backslash \\ and\nnew#line'
```

Comment: Thank you, it's all working now, to see how the match groups can be used really helped me along with escaping backslashes.